# Issues with pyenv-virtualenv: Python and PIP not changed when activating / deactivating virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, pyenv

I installed `pyenv-virtualenv` using Linuxbrew (Homebrew 2.2.5) on my Ubuntu 16.04 VPS. The pyenv version is: `1.2.16`. Now when I do a test like this:

```
pyenv install 3.8.1
pyenv virtualenv 3.8.1 test
cd /.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/test
pyenv local 3.8.1
```

Then entering / leaving the `/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/test` doesn't activate deactivate the virtual environment and I don't see `(test) username:~` in my shell. I also created a `/home/users/test` directory and `.python-version` there but still entering / leaving directory does nothing.

Accordingn to the [documentation](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv):

> If eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)" is configured in your shell,
>   pyenv-virtualenv will automatically activate/deactivate virtualenvs on
>   entering/leaving directories which contain a .python-version file that
>   contains the name of a valid virtual environment as shown in the
>   output of pyenv virtualenvs (e.g., venv34 or 3.4.3/envs/venv34 in
>   example above) . .python-version files are used by pyenv to denote
>   local Python versions and can be created and deleted with the pyenv
>   local command.

**So first question is: Why this doesn't work? Why the virtual environment is not activated / deactivated automatically at entering / leaving a directory containing a `.python-version` file?**

Also when I activate virtualenv by hand `pyenv activate test` and then check the Python version, it prints the system Python version and not the one from environment: `Python 3.8.1`:

```
python --version
Python 3.7.6
```

I can get the right Python version only by directly referring to virtualenv shims Python like this:

```
which python
/home/andre/.pyenv/shims/python
/home/andre/.pyenv/shims/python --version
Python 3.8.1
```

The behaviour is the same whenever the virtualenv "test" is activated or not.
I would expect that after activating "test" the command `python --version` returns `Python 3.8.1`

**So second question: why `pip` and `python` are not switched when activating / deactivating the virtual environment ?**

Are these pyenv bugs? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out that in order to automatically activate / deactivate a `venv` when entering / leaving a directory the `.python-version` file in there must contain the `venv name` and not the `Python version` associated with that `venv`

So executing:
`pyenv local 3.8.1`
creates a `.python-version` file which only includes the Python version `3.8.1`.
Then entering / leaving a directory containing `.python-version` file will set / unset the Python version specified in that file but will not activate / deactivate any `venv`.

To create a `.python-version` file that will do both: activate a virtual environment and set Python version the command should look like: `pyenv local test` where `test` is a venv created with:
`pyenv virtualenv 3.8.1 test`.

So changing `3.8.1` to `test` in the `.python-version` fixed the problem.
After I done this the `venv` was activated / deactivated when entering / leaving directory containing `.python-version`.

But still the Python version did not change to the one associated with the `venv` (in this case `3.8.1`)

Then I found out that I had two lines in my `.profile` that was causing this problem:

```bash
alias python=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/python3
alias pip=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/pip3
```

After removing these lines everything works as expected.

If still having any problems make sure you have these lines in your `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, whichever one you are using:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"

eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
  export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
  eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

Comment: How did you come up with this solution? Is it experimental or you have found some nice source of information about pyenv internals elswhere? I mean pyenv is great but official docs are somewhat obscure about low-level details.

Comment: For the first issue I was asking a little bit around... I think it's confusing for many people as `.python-version` suggests it contains the Python version but in fact it must contain the virtual environment name (what is actually clearly stated in the docs, but still I made this mistake...) The second issue was caused by myself.

Comment: THANK YOU! I would have never figured this out because `pyenv local --help` returns `Usage: pyenv local <version> <version2> <..>`. That is so *very* deceiving.

Answer (score 9):

I also had similar problem. The solution was to change the entries I put in my `~/.bashrc`. I went on to export the variable `export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"` and added the line `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"`.

Run the command below in full and it will add the necessary entries to the `~/.bashrc` of the user you are using.

```
read -r -d '' FILE_CONTENT << 'HEREDOC'
BEGIN

# >>>>>>
# pyenv configurations.

export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)" # This only sets up the path stuff.
eval "$(pyenv init -)" # This makes pyenv work in the shell.
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)" # Enabling virtualenv so it works natively.
# <<<<<<

END
HEREDOC
echo -n "${FILE_CONTENT:6:-3}" | tee -a ~/.bashrc
```

**NOTE:** Tested on Manjaro (Linux, Arch based).

**Thanks! =D**

[**Ref(s).:** https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer , https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv , https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/ , https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv/issues/390#issuecomment-852599456 ,
https://www.giters.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv/issues/407 ]