# Problems with pyenv virtualenv and Django 1.6

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, python-2.x, pyenv

I installed python 2.7 using pyenv to run an older project that still uses Django 1.6, but I can't get the path to work.

Even thou I have the virtualenv that I created with 2.7 activated, and all pip requirements installed, whenever I try to run the project I get the following error:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings '***.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named objects
```

*Name of the project was replaced by ***

When I try and print the os path I get this result:

```
\<module 'posixpath' from '/Users/userx/.pyenv/versions/2.7.18/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'\>
```

Instead of getting the directory for the Django project.

Does anyone know how can I get a python version installed with pyenv to run on the correct directory?

ps.: already tried this [ImportError: Could not import settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987648/importerror-could-not-import-settings) and already tried this [Issues with pyenv-virtualenv: Python and PIP not changed when activating / deactivating virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60212658/issues-with-pyenv-virtualenv-python-and-pip-not-changed-when-activating-deact) and everything regarding pyenv init settings and path

Comment: `os.path` is a module created from either `posixpath` (that's your case) or `ntpath`. Import is done using `sys.path` so do `import sys; print sys.path`

Comment: `pyenv virtualenv` creates virtualenvs normally outside of project dirs and has nothing to to with your project location. If your DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is `myproject.settings`, check that you have a `myproject` subfolder with an `__init__.py` and the settings.py has no syntax errores.